# Silverlight/OSX: TCP Socket stops working on one end?

Tags: c#, silverlight, macos, sockets, tcp

What could cause a socket to stop working on one end?

For example: I'm using a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` and use it to transfer binary data. However on select occasions the client-end of the socket stops working. Data still gets received from the server and works as expected. The client code also seems to work fine (no exceptions up to the actual Write) but the data is magically lost and never arrives to the server.

**Additions:**

One of the features of our software allows people to upload files through an out-of-browser silverlight application.

This error happens specifically when using the application on Mac OSX and uploading multiple files. This works fine on Windows! And uploading just a single file on OSX works fine as well.

Comment: Memory issues.. Another app attempting to use the socket.. Antivirus/firewall detecting something that looks fishy...  Network card failure... Could be a lot of things.  You'd expect to see an exception being thrown on any of them, though.  Is there a try/catch that's somehow masking exceptions so you don't see them, perhaps?

Comment: I stepped through the code and there are no exceptions. Please take a look at the additional info I put in the opening post.

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of reasons.  there could be a network hickup braking the connection; the client could fail, etc.

Are you catching exceptions when communicating with the socket on the client?